# How to show images on web pages using Ajax in Flask?

Tags: python, ajax, image, flask, upload

I am a newbie in Python Flask. Although, I have done this task multiple time in PHP/Java, somehow I am stuck here.

My task is to upload the image onto server, then display the image on web page, do some processing on image and again display the processed image on client machine.

To this end, I am using the code at [flask-fileupload-ajax-example](https://github.com/moremorefor/flask-fileupload-ajax-example) on Github. I am able to show the filename as well as its size correctly using ajax on the web page. But, somehow, when I try to set the `src` of `<img>` tag by the path of the uploaded images, it gives a `404, File not found error`.

Following are the relevant code snippets.

In `app.py`

```
@app.route('/uploadajax', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def upldfile():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        files = request.files['file']
        print(files)
        if files and allowed_file(files.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(files.filename)
            app.logger.info('FileName: ' + filename)
            print('FileName: ' + filename)
            updir = os.path.join(basedir, 'upload/')
            files.save(os.path.join(updir, filename))
            file_size = os.path.getsize(os.path.join(updir, filename))
            file_path = '/'.join(['upload', filename])
            return jsonify(name=filename, path=file_path, size=file_size)
```

In `app.js` file:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_data = new FormData($('#uploadform')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/uploadajax',
        data: form_data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        console.log(data);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log('Success!');
        $("#resultFilename").text(data['name']); // name of the file
        $("#resultFilesize").text(data['size']); // size of the file
        //my_url = "{{ url_for('upload', filename="+data['name']+" }}";
        $("#image").attr('src', data['path']); // setting the src attribute of img tag
        $("#adv-btn").attr('value', data['name']);
        $("#adv-btn").show();
        //get_image(data['name'])
    }).fail(function(data){
        alert('error!');
    });
});
```

I have also tried using `url_for` but it's not getting rendered. Any suggestion will be hugely appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this
Create a folder called static under the root of your application, and move your upload folder in there.

Then define your application like this

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path="/static", static_folder="static")
app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"] = "/root_flask_app/static/upload/"
```

Then inside app.py try:

```
updir = app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"]
```

and inside app.js:

```
$("#image").attr('src', '/static/'+data['path']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, the `url_for` is generating this url.. `http://localhost:5000/%7B%7B%20url_for('static',%20filename=upload/file.jpg%20%7D%7D`

Comment: what about this ... 
$("#image").attr('src', '/static/'+data['path']);

Comment: It's working. I don't know how, but it's working. Do you have any theories how does it so? Thanks a ton. :)

Comment: Hi Gio, apparently `url_for()` will only execute on server where Flask/Python will render the html pages. Hence, the above usage of setting the attribute will not work if we use 'Ajax/JQuery'. Can you please edit your question to your comment, so that I can accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding the theory, the content you are trying to display, is physically sitting somewhere, while the url path you are using probably it's not. For example if you define your @app.route('/whatever/uploadajax') it will continue to work at http://localhost/whatever/uploadajax ... but you don't have a folder called whatever.  With this in mind, the use of static_folder is just a workaround to define a path that your application will be able to find. I hope I have been clear ...

Comment: Hi phenom in regard to url_for, I have already edited the comment. If that is what you have asked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171702/discussion-between-gioachino-bartolotta-and-phenom-aks).